# Remove ShutDown, Login, Welcome, Logout message

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown, windows-iot-core

I searching for a way to remove/hide the message that appears during ShutDown, Login, Logout step as you can see below:

[image: Shutting down Windows message]

I have a Windows 10 IoT Entreprise LTSC v 21H2

If you have any ideas, do not hesitate. Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask, then come back and edit your question.

Comment: The messages are informative and help you manage your computer. What do you gain by removing them?  Time not well spent.

Comment: AFAIK, these can't be removed - the Shutdown/Logout messages can be made verbose, but I'm not aware of any way to entirely remove them _(as @John mentions, they're status messages and do serve an actual purpose. such as informing the user if any of the three hang for an extended period of time, indicating an issue)_

Comment: Yes - the messages are built in and not removable